# Can the .NET 5 SDK be used to compile .NET Core 3.1 projects?

Tags: .net, .net-core

We are starting a new project with .NET 5. The build server has the .NET Core 3.1 SDK installed. I was planning to also install the .NET 5 SDK side by side on the same server. Can I remove the .NET Core 3.1 SDK and use .NET 5 to compile both types of projects?

Comment: Did you try it? what happened? There's two separate things here: there's the *build tools*, and the *framework reference assemblies*; you can absolutely use the .NET 5 build tools to build things that target pretty much any TFM if the TFM's framework reference assemblies exit - but the question is: does .NET 5 include the .NET Core 3.1 framework reference assemblies, for it to use during the build. I'd be suspicious that it does not, so you'd need both SDKs.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I'm trying to build a 3.1 project with the .NET 5 SDK on my PC and it seems OK so far. I noticed that Visual Studio 2019 put dotnet.exe version 5.0.5 on the PC but it also supports creating and building .NET 3.1 Core project templates.

Comment: you can use `dotnet --info` at the command-line to see what runtimes are installed (and which build SDKs are installed, but what you're interested in is probably the runtimes)

Comment: The --info makes it more clear how this works. I also looked at the install folder C:Program Files\dotnet. There are subfolders under sdk for multiple versions. The product was clearly designed with side by side scenarios in mind. After I installed .NET 5 it replaced dotnet.exe with a new version and then added a new 5.0.202 sdk subfolder. My previous .NET Core 3.1 projects are unaffected. Very nice design!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the .NET 5 SDK can and will readily compile .NET Core 3.1 projects. You need to set `<TargetFramework>` appropriately.  It's very easy to make a mistake and use later language features if you don't set `<LangVersion>` but the resulting binaries will run using .NET Core 3.1.

The references might not be there, but if they're not there they will be fetched by `dotnet restore` just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There was no need to remove .NET Core 3.1. After installing .NET 5 a new SDK subfolder was added and existing SDK folder for 3.1 was left. Now projects for either SDK version can be built on the server.